# Bottom few inches of drywall got wet, but wall looks fine. Do I have to replace that drywall?

Tags: water, drywall, basement, mold, damage

So my basement bathroom backed up, and some water (mild sewage too I guess) spilled to floor, and made its way under the wall. I have sprayed enough mold killer, and Clorox to kill an elephant,  and so far I see no issues. When I tap on the drywall it also feels fine. It is painted in case that matters.

What I really want to know is if I have to replace the drywall of the bathroom? The other side of that wall is not drywall and I am replacing it anyways. (I hope that makes sense).

Comment: Why are you replacing the other side of the wall?

Comment: So let me get my terms clear so I make sense. If inside the bathroom we call those walls the interior walls, then it is the exterior walls I am replacing anyways. Those walls are old shiplap style on one side, and old drywall that was never painted on the other side. I do a bit of drwalling, so Im not scared to replace it, I just dont want to in the inside of the bathroom because of the tight quarters (around toilet, baseboard heater etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not replace the drywall for 1 short term “flood”
We don’t know what kind of drywall at this point, water resistant can actually Handel water better than standard Sheetrock, my concern would be more getting it sanitized more than mold but it sounds like you have cleaned it up, if you don’t see wrinkles going up the wall the Sheetrock was probably not affected. When you see wrinkles were the gypsum absorbs the water and swells that’s when Sheetrock looses its strength but that takes some time.

I think you are fine to leave it in place.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So far I havent seen wrinkles. Ill be sure to look closer just in case.

Comment: When there is a problem especially with un painted you can see it from 20’ when you pull the other side down I doubt the paper has even wicked up 1/2” and that’s with the additional cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

If you started mopping up the water right away and limited the water under the wall you should be alright. There's usually a small gap between the drywall and the floor so that would help in the drywall not absorbing a lot of water.
Now if the water was an inch or two deep and soaking into the drywall, then you've got a problem because the strength of the drywall would be compromised. You'd probably want to replace it.

Comment: The water probably never got more than a fraction of an inch deep, as the carpet at the door never got wet. It was the wall near the toilet that saw some water seep under/around tile floor edges